# Daylight time in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new SQL Developer user and haven't worked a lot with changing dates. I have a query which is showing information 1 hour past the actual time. It is because one of the tables in which the data is pulled from has the date always in **CST** while other tables consider the system date which has **CDT** or **CST** depends on the time of year

When I join the tables, they start 1 hour past the actual time. To compensate for this, I have to use `DELIVERY_TIME+1/24` instead of `DELIVERY_TIME` but the codes need to be changed twice a year.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: store everything in utc, and do all comparisons/calculations using utc. then you convert to "local" TZ for display purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'l want to store all your database values as UTC whenever possible as these are as universal as you're going to get. You can render these out as local times in your application layer as these settings are often highly specific to the individual viewing the data.

If you have a particular delivery time every day, like 6pm, and you want to know where that time falls in UTC you can construct the time and convert it to UTC. Most time-zones that observe some form of DST flop back and forth 1h in their local time, but do not in UTC.

Normally there are functions like `MAKEDATE()` or `MAKETIME()` available in your database that can construct arbitrary points in time. Use those to make a time in your preferred timezone, then switch to UTC to keep them "fixed".

Any time you have code that "must be changed twice a year" you will have code that *doesn't* get changed and then chaos will ensue. Don't do this. You're just setting yourself up for failure.

As a note, doing this all in SQL can be very messy since databases don't always have up to date timezone information unless they lean heavily on the operating system. Your operating system is generally better equipped, it should get patched if things changed like [it did in 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_Act_of_2005). Even that was a total mess since a mix of patched and unpatched systems were in constant conflict.

Comment: Even if I convert to UTC, the CST to UTC will have a different value then CDT to UTC. And in the end it will be the same thing. Is there any way to implement daylight correction in SQL when the table has times only in CST?

Comment: Ideally you get rid of the CST times and convert them to UTC so that they can be rendered out in CDT or CST or CST/CDT as necessary. There's many ways of expressing these times values. UTC is the only way to guarantee they don't jump back and forth depending on the time of year.